# angular/ts global variable assigned in async call undefined in constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I'm using HTTP calls to my Web API to retrieve 2 API keys to use another API.

These API keys get retrieved through 2 functions: 
`getApiKey()` and `getAppId()`

When I call those functions inside the constructor the value returned by them, which is a global variable, is undefined.

When I call it outside of the constructor it works fine.

I don't want to use global variables, but when I try to create a variable inside the `getApiKey()` or `getAppid()` function body and assign it inside the http.get call, it also returns undefined.

I'm guessing this has to do with `http.get` being asynchronous, but I have no idea how to fix it/how to make it wait for the response.

Here's my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Constants } from '../../utils/constants';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipes',
  templateUrl: './recipes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipes.component.css']
})
export class RecipesComponent {
  appid;  
  appkey;
  matchesList;  
  recipeSearchForm: FormGroup;
  notFoundError: boolean = false;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.searchRecipeInit();    //undefined here

    this.recipeSearchForm = new FormGroup({
      recipeSearchInput: new FormControl()
    });
  }

  getApiKey(){
    this.http.get(Constants.GET_YUMMLY_APP_KEY, this.getOptionsSimple()).subscribe((res: Response) => {  
      this.appkey = res.text();
      console.log(this.appkey);   
    });
    return this.appkey;    
  }

  getAppId(){
    this.http.get(Constants.GET_YUMMLY_APP_ID, this.getOptionsSimple()).subscribe((res: Response) => {  
      this.appid = res.text(); 
      console.log(this.appid);      
    });
    return this.appid;    
  } 

  getSearchParams(){
    // get from search text field
    var str = this.recipeSearchForm.get('recipeSearchInput').value
    // split into words and add + in between
    if(str != null) {
      var correctFormat = str.split(' ').join('+');
      return correctFormat          
    }
    return str
  }

  getOptions(){
    var headers = new Headers();

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );    
    headers.append('X-Yummly-App-Key',this.getApiKey());    
    headers.append('X-Yummly-App-ID',this.getAppId());

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return options;
  }

  getOptionsSimple(){
    var headers = new Headers();

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' ); 

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return options;
  }

  searchRecipe() {     
      // not undefined here
      this.http.get(Constants.GET_SEARCH_RECIPE+this.getSearchParams(), this.getOptions()).subscribe((res: Response) => {  
        this.matchesList = res.json().matches;

        console.log(this.matchesList);
        if(this.matchesList.length == 0){
          this.notFoundError = true;
        }
        else{
          this.notFoundError = false;
        }
      },
      (err) => {
        if(err.status == 400){
          // Bad Request
        }
        else if(err.status == 409){
          // API Rate Limit Exceeded
        }
        else if(err.status == 500){
          // Internal Server Error
        }
      });
  }

  searchRecipeInit() {     
    this.http.get(Constants.GET_SEARCH_RECIPE+"", this.getOptions()).subscribe((res: Response) => {  
      this.matchesList = res.json().matches;

      this.notFoundError = false;      
    },
    (err) => {
      if(err.status == 400){
        // Bad Request
      }
      else if(err.status == 409){
        // API Rate Limit Exceeded
      }
      else if(err.status == 500){
        // Internal Server Error
      }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you've included works as expected. This question is possibly a duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)
, but since it's more about observables I'll answer it.

Your misunderstanding of asynchronous code is the main problem, and specifically code like the following

```
getAppId() {
    this.http.get(Constants.GET_YUMMLY_APP_ID, this.getOptionsSimple()) // 1
        .subscribe((res: Response) => {                                 // 
            this.appid = res.text();                                    // 3
            console.log(this.appid);                                    // 4
        });
    return this.appid;                                                  // 2
}
```

The code is executed in the numbered order as labeled to the right. Since TypeScript/JavaScript is synchronous, it will fire the `http.get(...)` function, and then continue to the next line, which in this case is the `return this.appid;`. What value does `this.appid` have at this time? `undefined`, thus it's working as expected.

You'll have to return the result of the `http.get(...)`, which isn't available until it's `.subscribe()` function is called.

Since you're relying on two separate `http.get(...)` calls, the one for the `apiKey` and one for the `appId`, you can utilize Rx operators to "wait" for both of them to finish/emit values. In this case, the one that comes to mind is the `Observable.zip()` function.

I've created a snippet that should guide you in the correct direction to get your code working as expected.

```
class SearchRecipeDemo {

  private getAppId() {
    return this.http.get(Constants.GET_YUMMLY_APP_ID);
  }

  private getApiKey() {
    return this.http.get(Constants.GET_YUMMLY_APP_KEY);
  }

  private init(): void {
    this.searchRecipe();
  }

  private getOptions() {
    return Rx.Observable.zip(getApiKey(), getAppId()).map((result) => {
        // Prints your keys
        console.log(`apiKey: ${result[0].text()}`);
        console.log(`appId: ${result[1].text()}`);

        // Create the RequestOptions
        let headers = new Headers();

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('X-Yummly-App-Key', result[0].text());
        headers.append('X-Yummly-App-ID', result[1].text();

          const options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers
          });
          return options;
        });
    });

  private searchRecipe() {
    this.getOptions().map((options) => {
        // Options here is the RequestOptions object returned from the 'getOptions' function
        console.log(options);

        //Make your request to search the recipe here
      })
      .subscribe();
  }
}

new SearchRecipeDemo().init();
```

Have a look a slightly different version of the code in this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/repekanefu/edit?js,console) JSBin snippet that mocks the observables.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! I understand most of it, the only thing I'm still don't quite understand is how I should bind my appkey and appid to the response of my http call in this scenario. Do I make the http calls inside the getOptions body?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a slightly different code snippet that matches your app a bit more. I replaced the mocked observables with calls to the `getApiKey()` and `getAppId()` functions. Note that I've also changed those functions to return the observable from the `http.get()` call. I couldn't really figure out why you had the `getOptionsSimple()` so I omitted and refactored the code a bit.